# Behance API does not display all projects?

Tags: json, api, behance-api

The issue specifically is that when I am trying to retrieve the data from my behance portfolio, I only get 7 projects. I uploaded approximately 30 projects and they are not being returned by the Behance API.

It is not showing all the projects that my account/user HAS. I simply want to get the covers of each project and display them. This works with other users such as Ilya Kuvshinov.

I am using localhost to test the API and only get 5 out of 28 projects.

Does the Behance API take a long time to update information? Is there a setting I need to have to get the API to show all projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behance's API is limited to very low amount of requests (150 per hour) so maybe your problem is one of these two (i could help you out better if you shared some code with us):

1. Your entire projects need more than 150 calls
2. You have restricted projects that will not shown to an unauthorized user (like nudity projects with adult content)

To solve first problem you had to manage your API calls under 150 per hour, or simply contact to behance support team and share your problem with them. For second one you most change your API request to an authorized API request that's need to follow behance API documentation. Simple as that, kind regards